# Center CollectionView in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, frontend

I'm attempting to center a collection of icons vertically and horizontally within a rectangle. I can only center them along the X or Y axis, and that is determined by the orientation in my GridItemsLayout. I can manually set the icon size to make it fit into the box, but that is sloppy and may not look the same on different devices. I'd like for the icons to center and automatically size themselves.

Here is a screenshot of the items in the Grid it stands with the following code. The icons in question are in the green box:

[image]

Here is the code for the Grid - the CollectionView at question is the final CollectionView.

```
<Grid
    Padding="3"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
    ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*">
    <Image Source="{Binding DisplayIcon}" />
    <Grid RowDefinitions="auto,auto,*" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label
            Grid.Row="0"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="Medium"
            Text="{Binding Name}"
            VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        <ProgressBar
            Grid.Row="2"
            Progress="{Binding Progress}"
            ProgressColor="{StaticResource Secondary}"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
    </Grid>
    <CollectionView
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Grid.Column="4"
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ProgressIcons}">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Span="3"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image BackgroundColor="Transparent" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: AFAIK images don't automatically resize. If you use an image without setting a specific size, it will just use the image as-is. Can you clarify a little more what exactly you want to achieve? Do you intend to have two colums in the green box? Could you also improve the formatting of the code for better legibility?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Yes, I want to have two columns in the green box, automatically centered and sized. If I cannot control the sizing, then at least centered on both the x and y axis.

Comment: According to your screenshot, do you want the form to adapt difference device automatically? In addition, is this format in the screenshot you finally want?